# Why does PDFSIZEOPT not reduce file size much?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, file-size

I am using [pdfsizeopt](https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt/blob/master/README.txt) to try to minimise a large pdf document. The original size is 27.8 MB and contains around 120 images. Most are jpg, some are png.

I run the command `pdfsizeopt/pdfsizeopt input.pdf output.pdf` but the output file is 93% of the original size ~25MB.

Is there a way to reduce the file size further?

Comment: Compressing something that has already been compressed doesn't save much. What's the total size of the images?

Comment: @egreg The figures folder is 27.4MB

Comment: What type of images are they (photographs, diagrams, data plots, etc.)?

Comment: @IanThompson There are some colour images, some b&w images/plots and some png plots.

When I saved the JPGs, I tried to reduce their file size by setting the horizontal dimension to ~1200 pixels

Comment: Try exporting the plots as either pdf or eps files.

Comment: I was able to export some of the files to pdf as a trial. The jpeg was 93 KB and reduced to 61 KB.

I guess if the 30% size reduction is true for all files I could reduce to 10 MB overall?

Long week of exporting files ahead!

Comment: It depends. Assuming your application is exporting to pdf in an efficient way, you can think about it like this. A jpg file stores the colour of each pixel. A pdf graphic stores a set of geometric instructions. For (say) a plot of a few curves, the pdf version is likely to be much smaller. On the other hand, jpg usually does better for an image with very complicated shading.

Comment: @IanThompson Yes, I am quickly realising that! Some images are resulting in larger pdf files than jpg files. I dont think this is an effective use of my time!

Is there another work around that could be used?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any. What software created the files?

Comment: I use software called CorelDRAW

Answer (score 2):

I always have a better compression with `gs`, both Tex-produced and scanned pdf files.

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=144 -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=144 -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dMonoImageResolution=144 -sOutputFile=compressed.pdf original.pdf
```

`-dPDFSETTINGS=` specifies the quality /resolution of the output PDF. You can choose from the following:

- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` (72 dpi images)
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` (150 dpi images)
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer` (300 dpi images)
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` (300 dpi images, color preserving)
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/default`

Comment: How would I run such a script? From command prompt?

Comment: @phald Yes, you run it from command line.

Comment: Okay thanks, I tried that but I see an error:
`"gs" is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: you will need to install `ghostscript` for your system, https://www.ghostscript.com/.

Comment: I have `Ghostscript 9.26` installed on managed desktop  and it shows in the programs of the start menu

Comment: what system are you using? try `ghostscript` instead `gs`.

Comment: I got this message when executing the command
`**** Error 'gs' ignored -- ExtGState missing from Resources. Output may be incorrect.` And the resulting file was then larger than the original file.